# How to change the color or style of a chart in word with office-js add-in

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I want to create a word add-in which can change the color or style of a chart, but I can't find samples in Script Lab. When I search this in API reference, only find the way to do this through Excel add-in.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to JS API, You could refer to [Word API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word?view=word-js-preview) document, all word JS APIs are listed here. From this list, you could see that charting API does not support in Word so far.

So I would suggest that you could create a request in UserVoice to submit this request and upvote your request.https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback?category_id=163566